# Why is "Successfully" installed Multi-Project Template for Visual Studio 2010 not appearing anywhere?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I created a multi-project template using the example from [vsix.codeplex.com](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)

When I hit run, the extension is installed and works in the Experimental Instance of Visual Studio 2010.

When I try to install it (to the non experimental instances), despite the installation succeeded message and the files being copied to:

```
%LocalAppdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions
```

I can not find the extension in the "Extension Manager" or see the template in the "Add New Project" dialog.

After uninstalling from experimental instance and deleting copied files,
I noticed that after installing files are copied to both

```
%LocalAppdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions
```

and

```
%LocalAppdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\Extensions
```

and the extension appears in the experimental instance's extension manager, but not in the regular instance's extension manager.

VS's activity log states extension is loaded and enabled.

Extension works on non-experimental instance on another PC.

Perhaps there is another extension/add-on that I have that overrides this one?

Tried changing snk files and GUIDs, didn't help.

Comment: How are you installing to the non-Experimental VSIX? Are you just double-clicking the VSIX file and following the wizard?

Comment: @Aaron, is there any way for me to debug this, or should I turn to MS tech support?

Comment: Take a look at the Activity Log to see if your extension is being discovered: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Comment: Successfully loaded and enabled, yet I can't find it in extension manager or in add new project (even with search)!? - Update: I just checked on another PC (should have tried that earlier!) and there it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing my regular instance's extensions to experimental instance (redownloading them one by one), and running my extension after every few installations, I found that indeed a specific extension prevents my extension from loading (despite log files state it was successfully loaded).

So if you have this problem you can use this workflow:

1. Make a list of all extension you have installed in VS2010.
2. Load your extension's sln, configured to run experimental instance of VS.
3. Run (Ctrl+F5).
4. Uninstall your extension, install other extensions.
5. Close experimental instance of VS.
6. Run (Ctrl+F5).
7. If your extension appears in extension manager, goto 4, if not goto 8.
8. Try uninstalling one of the latest installed extensions from experimental instance of VS.
9. Close experimental instance of VS.
10. Run (Ctrl+F5).
11. If your extension now appears you have found the colliding extension. If not goto 8.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link and repair you will then see the MVC 4 project.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683